# How to create geochart of Gujarat State in react?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-google-charts

I am trying to create the geochart in React. Like this one [image: Sample Image]

I tried `react-google-charts` and `react-leaflet` but they're not compatible with this. Leaflet somehow tries to complete the job, but it seems complex. Is there any method to do this?

Data will be passed as the Object Array - Like this, { "Ahmedabad":2, "Amreli":3,... }
You can check this graph here: [Paintmaps Demo](https://paintmaps.com/map-charts/245c/Gujarat-map-chart)

Can you help me with what should I do?

Comment: Do you have at least the data that is presented on the map because neither you mention anything relevant nor you provide any relevant code. What does the map show? Population, sth else?

Comment: I would use react-leaflet and use a geojson layer to show the outline, name and data. 
Here is an example from the leaflet documentation: 
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/
However if you use react as your framework I always recommend using the react-leaflet package, therefore you will have to adapt some of the parts in the example to a more react way of thinking. Looks like this blogg post covers everything you need to make it work:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/